# Cordova - module org.apache.cordova.file.File not found

Tags: android, cordova, cmd

I am developing apps with Cordova.

I have build an app and when calling this in cli `cordova run android --device`
it's deploying my app on the device. While debugging on chrome I get:

```
module org.apache.cordova.file.File not found
```

Why is that ?

In my config.xml file I have the following:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="3.0.0" />
```

and the plugin is located in `cordova\platforms\android\platform_www\plugins`

The `cordova` version is `4.1.1`.

What is the difference in these below ?

```
org.apache.cordova.file.File
org.apache.cordova.file
```

Consolelogs

```
xxxx.$application::launch()
file:///android_asset/www/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.woff?n6lnws Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
file:///android_asset/www/resources/images/favicon.ico Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
file:///android_asset/www/resources/ext-watermark/fonts/ext-watermark.ttf?n6lnws Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
app.js:1 ::::Cordova DeviceReady::::
app.js:1 Require: org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser.inappbrowser
app.js:1 Require: org.apache.cordova.file.File
cordova.js:59 Uncaught module org.apache.cordova.file.File not found
```

Comment: Did you `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file` + `cordova build android`?

Comment: Hi, I have tried this without any luck.

Comment: Can you please add the complete error stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this issue was arising because of dependent plug-in i.e. `org.apache.cordova.media-capture`

If you have `media-capture` plugin installed, you would see inside `org.apache.cordova.media-capture.MediaFile.js` file there is the file dependent code

```
var utils = require('cordova/utils'),
exec = require('cordova/exec'),
File = require('org.apache.cordova.file.File'),
CaptureError = require('./CaptureError');
```

**Solution:**

I have removed the `media-capture` plugin for now and looking for an update which doesn't ask for old cordova file plugin API.

`cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.media-capture`

I understand that it wouldn't solve your problem completely, but you should be good to go ahead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I saw that although I added a newer version of cordova-plugin-file Cordova still used an older version. Removing /platforms and rerunning `cordova platform add android` did the trick

Comment: This is more comment than an answer.